# ¿Cómo obtener nombre de las columnas de una relación de muchos a muchos en Laravel / Eloquent?

Tags: eloquent

Tengo una relación de muchos a muchos entre "products" y "categories", puedo obtener datos de esta relación a partir de su nombre en el modelo en el que me encuentro (que es parte de la misma), entonces estoy en el modelo "Product", y de esta forma:

```
$thisModel = (new self); // A new empty Model
$relation  = (new self)->$relationName();
$relatedModel = $relation->getRelated(); // A new empty Model
```

*Código de la siguiente respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56089111/3919660*

Tengo los dos modelos conectados y puedo obtener sus nombres. Necesito los campos que corresponden a las FKs en la tabla intermedia. Si hago un trazado de la relación:

```
dd($relation);
```

Tengo lo siguiente:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#1377 ▼
  #table: "category_product"
  #foreignPivotKey: "product_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "category_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "categories"
  #pivotColumns: []
  ...
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener los nombres de los campos que relacionan "products" y "categories" de esta relación?

***Nota:** actualmente estoy obteniendo estos datos a partir una RAW query:*

```
$query = 'SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "skyerp" AND TABLE_NAME = "' . $tableName . '" AND 
    COLUMN_KEY!="PRI" AND DATA_TYPE="bigint"';
```

> Editado: category_product tiene los campos:

```
id
category_id
product_id
```

quiero poder recuperar los dos últimos, que guardan la referencia a las tablas "categories" y "products",
por supuesto, yo en principio no se el nombre de la tabla intermedia ni sus campos, ni las tablas relacionadas*.

*Parto de un modelo que tiene una relación cuyo nombre conozco, en este caso "categories", también tengo fácil acceso al nombre de la tabla que "mapea" este modelo:

```
$tableName = (new self)->getTableName();
```

Comment: puedes utilizar load(), o utilizar with() para pre cargar las relaciones y acceder a ellas

Comment: Quieres obtener los nombres de los campos de la tabla `category_product`?

Comment: Yo no termino de entender cuáles columnas deseas recuperar, puedes explicar mejor?